# Need help in running presto execute query

Tags: cassandra, presto

I need to query bunch of ticket numbers which get it from ServiceNow (I'm using Cassandra DB).

I query cassandra using presto --execute command but I can use only one ticket at a time, I tried using --file but it didn't work.

```
./prestocli --server https:////10.x.x.x:8081 --catalog cassandra --keystore-path=etc/catalog/presto_keystore.jks --keystore-password=xxxxxxx --execute --file /tmp/input.txt --output-format CSV > /tmp/output_1.csv
```

it failed to process... (input.txt is were I have select statement as mentioned below and I tried saving this file and running as input.sql but no luck)

I use single find command

```
./prestocli --server https:////10.x.x.x:8081 --catalog cassandra --keystore-path=etc/catalog/presto_keystore.jks --keystore-password=xxxxxxx --execute "select inc_number, inc_state from incident_table where inc_number = 'INCxxxxxx';" --output-format CSV > /tmp/output.csv
```

Can any one suggest the best of doing this using presto?

Cassandra v3.11.3
Presto v0.215

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't understand the actual issue. Could you update the description? Also, you can ask such a question in the community Slack prestosql.io/slack.html.

Comment: As suggested I have started my conversation in presto slack channel.... https://app.slack.com/client/TFKPX15NC/CGB0QHWSW